# PHP - Remove extra comma

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 post variables & i need to save those 3 variable values in single field in mysql table

```
below are table field details:
-------------------------------
id int(11)
name varchar(100)
country varchar(100)

details varchar(100) (this field used for store all 3 variables value)
```

if variable values are posted as id=1, name-steve & country=usa then needs to store as

RESULT - **1,steve,usa**

now problem is all 3 variable are optional so if passed just id & name needs to store as

RESULT - **1,steve** (no last comma will be store)

if passed just id & country then needs to store as

RESULT - **1,usa** (no additional comma will be stored)

I have tried like:

```
if(isset($data['id']) || isset($data['name']) || isset($data['country']))
{
    $details=$data['id'].",".$data['name'].",".$data['country'];
}
```

How can i achieve this in php-mysql ?

Comment: Storing multiple values in a single database field is rarely a good idea.... why don't you use multiple columns for the different values? When you read `1,usa` in a years time, how do you know that it's an `id` and `country` and not an `id` and `name`? Separate columns for the values would tell you instantly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put present values in an array and implode it after

```
$details = [];

if(isset($data['id']) and !empty($data['id'])) $details[] = $data['id'];
if(isset($data['name']) and !empty($data['name'])) $details[] = $data['name'];
if(isset($data['country']) and !empty($data['country'])) $details[] = $data['country'];
$details = implode(',', $details);
```

Comment: checked when only id & country passed then it stored 1,,usa

Comment: it's imposible. It can be only if $data['name'] is equal  to empty string

Comment: Check using `empty()` rather than `isset()`

Comment: @MarkBaker  it's not clear from the question :)  Moreover, both checks are required to avoid `undefined index`

Comment: @STEVE001 i've added check for empty data

Comment: I used empty() instead of isset() & its works perfectly.. @splash58 please update answer, so i can approve it :)

Comment: @STEVE001 Save both tests because if data array will not contain any key, you will receive error

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
if(isset($data['id']) || isset($data['name']) || isset($data['country']))
{
$details=$data['id'].",".$data['name'].",".$data['country'];
}
```

Just add this after your code . 
And you are done.

```
$details = trim($details,',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '';
foreach($details as $k=>$v) { if($v) $text .= ($text?',':'') . $v; }
```